# React draft wysiwyg - Can't able to type text in editor after clearing editorState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I'm trying to reset editor content after some action completed using `react-draft-wysiwyg` editor. All contents cleared by using `clearEditorContent` method from `draftjs-utils`. But after clearing contents I can't able to type nothing in editor. Added the code below. Please help to solve this problem.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { EditorState, convertToRaw, ContentState } from 'draft-js';
import { clearEditorContent } from 'draftjs-utils'
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import '../../../../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';
import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';

export default class RTEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
    };
    this.setDomEditorRef = ref => this.domEditor = ref;
  }

  onEditorStateChange: Function = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    }, () => {
      this.props.sendResult(draftToHtml(convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent())));
    });
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.reset) {
      this.reset();
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.text) {
      const html = `${this.props.text}`;
      const contentBlock = htmlToDraft(html);
      if (contentBlock) {
        const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
        const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
        this.setState({ editorState, });
      }
    }

    this.domEditor.focusEditor();
  }

  reset = () => {
      let {editorState} = this.state;
      editorState = clearEditorContent(editorState);
      this.setState({ editorState });
  };

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    return (
      <Editor
        ref={this.setDomEditorRef}
        editorState={editorState}
        wrapperClassName="rte-wrapper"
        editorClassName="rte-editor"
        onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
        toolbarCustomButtons={[this.props.UploadHandler]}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

My parent component code is below,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { addThreadPost } from '../../../api/thread-api'
import { isEmpty } from '../../../api/common-api'
import RTEditor from './Loadable'

export default class ThreadActivity extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            clearEditor: false,
            threadPost: ''
        }
    }

    setPost = (post) => {
        this.setState({ threadPost: post })
    }

    addThreadPost = () => {
        let postText = this.state.threadPost.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
        if(!isEmpty(postText)) {
            addThreadPost(this.props.match.params.id_thread, this.state.threadPost, this.state.postAttachments).then(response => {
                this.setState({ 
                    clearEditor: true,
                    postAttachments: [],
                })
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Please enter some text in box.");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return [
            <div className="commentbox-container">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="form-control">
                        <RTEditor 
                            ref={node => { this.threadPost = node }} 
                            text={""} 
                            sendResult={this.setPost.bind(this)}
                            reset={this.state.clearEditor}
                        />
                        <button className="btn-add-post" onClick={this.addThreadPost}>Add Post</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your parent component's code? Hunch is that the problem has to do with how you're managing the `reset` prop.

Comment: @TadasAntanavicius - Added parent component code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably that once you set `ThreadActivity`'s `state.clearEditor` to `true`, you never set it back to false. So your `this.reset()` is getting called every time the component receives props. Which, incidentally, is going to be every time you try to type because you're invoking that `this.props.sendResult`.

The simplest fix is to make sure you change `state.clearEditor` back to false once the clearing is done.

Add to ThreadActivity.js:

```js
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.completeClear = this.completeClear.bind(this);
}

...

completeClear = () => {
  this.setState({clearEditor: false});
}

render() {
  ...
  <RTEditor
   ...
   completeClear={this.completeClear}
  />
  ...
}
```

And in RTEditor.js:

```js
reset = () => {
    let {editorState} = this.state;
    editorState = clearEditorContent(editorState);
    this.setState({ editorState });
    this.props.completeClear();
};
```